# php interfaces with stricter signatures

Tags: php, interface

In php can I have an implementation of an interface with stricter function signatures than those specified?

for instance:

```
interface iChangeHandler{
    public function update($new, $old);
    }

class NoteChangeHandler implements iChangeHandler
{
    public function update(Note $new, Note $old)
    {
    //does stuff
    }
}
```

As an alternative I can do a check for the class or instanceof, just wondering if I can do this instead.

Comment: In short, No. Try it http://codepad.org/HHuGzMTM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not since implementation's signature must have exact match for declared prototype. So you can not use more narrow parameters restrictions. It's quite [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), actually:

> Note:
>
> The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method
>   signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result
>   in a fatal error.

Comment: I've seen TFM be pretty vague in many cases, thought I'd pose it to the crowd.